# How might the view for this widget be created?

Tags: android

Would something like this be a Bitmap placed in an ImageView, dynamically created with a Canvas object, or am I way off the mark? Want to be sure I'm thinking in the right direction. Any other classes I should look up? (I already understand how widgets work)

[image]

Comment: Yes, it's most likely a custom View converted into a a Bitmap, which was then set to an ImageView.

Comment: I think they made use of canvas class to draw on a bitmap anything they wanted like the graphic and the assets, and then passed that created bitmap into an ImageView or as background of a regular view...